# What does 'session.createQuery' do?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

What does :

```
session.createQuery(hqlString);
```

do ?

Does it also create and run the query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It creates a [Query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/Query.html) object and NO it does not run

Once the `Query` object is created, you can set the parameters using the `setParameter()` overloaded methods. and invoking `list()` on the query object runs the query and returns the list of result.

The Javadoc for `Query` class states that

> Queries are executed by calling list(), scroll() or iterate(). A query
>   may be re-executed by subsequent invocations. Its lifespan is,
>   however, bounded by the lifespan of the Session that created it.

Comment: then how do I run the query ?

Comment: and what does `setParameter` do ? Is `session.createQuery("use librarian").list()` not enough to execute the query ?

Comment: your query may have a where clause which may require you to set the query parameters.. example `from User as u where u.Id = :userId`.. here `userId` is a dynamic parameter to the query. If your query doesn't use any param for where clause then you can do it like above

Answer (score 0):

The createQuery will only instantiate the query object with the hql value you passed in.
It does not run the query, it will only be run when executeUpdate has been called.

More information can be found below.

createQuery:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#createQuery(java.lang.String)

executeUpdate:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#executeUpdate()

(Updated) Regarding to your comment on how to execute the query, an old tutorial can be found below:
http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-query-examples-hql/